# Taking out a text from a String as a Key from Json

Tags: json, node.js

I need to take out 1000 from this Key-Value Pair in node Js

```
"msg":"amamm : ErrorResponse  {\"abcd1\":{\"Status\":\"E\",\"rem\":{\"Code\":\"1000\",\"message\":\"Unable to access your information at this time.(1000)\"}}}"
```

Comment: I think this json is malformed. What is the amamm: ErrorResponse ?

Comment: The value as a whole is a string containing a json too.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON what you have posted is invalid. May be your JSON should be like the following:

```
var json =    {
        "msg": {
            "amm": {
                "ErrorResponse": {
                    "abcd1": {
                        "Status": "E",
                        "rem": {
                            "Code": "1000",
                            "message": "Unabletoaccessyourinformationatthistime.(1000)"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in node.js you have get the value using dot notation like as follows:

```
json.msg.amm.ErrorResponse.abcd1.rem.code
```

Will give you the value 1000

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get the string

```
amamm : ErrorResponse  {\"abcd1\":{\"Status\":\"E\",\"rem\":{\"Code\":\"1000\",\"message\":\"Unable to access your information at this time.(1000)\"}}}
```

by doing `err.msg`

You can get the json and then get the string you want. I copied the content of the msg into a variable `str` just to test the regex

```
var re = /\{.*?\}$/; 
var str = 'amamm : ErrorResponse  {\"abcd1\":{\"Status\":\"E\",\"rem\":{\"Code\":\"1000\",\"message\":\"Unable to access your information at this time.(1000)\"}}}';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    var content = JSON.parse(m[0]);
    console.log(content);
    console.log(content.abcd1.rem.Code);
}
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/sger1gk6/